# How to cout/printf a mat without e

Tags: opencv

I am a starter of programming openCV. And recently I have met a problem to print the value which seems quite different from Matlab. Have searched a lot, but none of them solve this question. The code is simply like this:

```
double asd1[4]={1.123456789123456789,1.111,1.11111,1.1111};

Mat f = Mat(1,4,CV_32F,asd1);

cout<<"f="<<f<<endl;

for (int y = 0; y < f.rows; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0;x < f.cols; ++x) {
        printf("%.3f ", f.at<double>(y, x));
    }
}
```

But it did not work. If I try to cout using `cout<<"f="<<f<<endl;` it will output weird values. Any idea? Will appreciate for any help.

Comment: Your above code just works fine with output `1.123 1.111 1.111 1.111`, what else is your requirement ?

Comment: use Mat f = Mat(1,4,CV_64F,asd1); since your array are double (64F) and not float (32F). then first try to cout << f << endl; What is try4? What does "But it did not work" mean? Error message? Output? Explain further please.

Comment: Well, I just re edited it. If I simply do cout << f << endl. It shows the results like: f = [-1.0826352e+012, 1.890432, -9.7609096e+028, 1.8888749]. If I do the following loop. The error message shows something like memory problem:'There is an unhandled exception at 0x75744878: Microsoft C ++ Exception:  at memory location 0x00dff454'.